# Error occured while implementing up navigation button in action bar : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, runtimeexception

iam working on project which implements navigation button in action bar, the following error raises. my project comprises of two java files, two xml files

ERROR AT LOGCAT:

```
07-17 14:19:02.277: D/gralloc_goldfish(2120): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-17 14:19:43.937: I/Choreographer(2120): Skipped 113 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-17 14:19:44.097: D/dalvikvm(2120): newInstance failed: Lcom/app/Nav; not accessible to Landroid/app/Instrumentation;
07-17 14:19:44.097: D/AndroidRuntime(2120): Shutting down VM
07-17 14:19:44.167: W/dalvikvm(2120): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4ab6ba8)
07-17 14:19:44.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2120): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 14:19:44.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2120): Process: com.app, PID: 2120
07-17 14:19:44.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2120): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.app/com.app.Nav}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
07-17 14:19:44.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
07-17 14:19:44.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-17 14:19:44.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-17 14:19:44.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-17 14:19:44.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-17 14:19:44.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-17 14:19:44.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-17 14:19:44.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 14:19:44.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-17 14:19:44.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-17 14:19:44.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-17 14:19:44.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-17 14:19:44.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2120): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
07-17 14:19:44.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-17 14:19:44.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
07-17 14:19:44.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
07-17 14:19:44.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
07-17 14:19:44.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2120):     ... 11 more
```

1)MainActivity.java

```
package com.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.linear_layout);
        Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.app.Nav.class));

            }
        });

    }

}
```

2)Nav.java

```
package com.app;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;



class Nav extends ActionBarActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.relative_layout);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        System.out.println("context entered");
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            System.out.println("menu nav");
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

}

3)AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.app.Nav"
            android:label="@string/up_icon" 
            android:parentActivityName="com.app.MainActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.app.MainActivity" />


        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nav class needs to be public.  Otherwise it can only be accessed from other classes in this package, and the Android framework class that launches the activity is in another package.  That causes an exception.